# Compression not enabled on autoptimize CSS and JS and SVG file

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, svg, compression

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flucidaphotography.com%2Fvancouver%2F&tab=desktop

The above link explains the issues with compression. Generally these items are covered with WP Performance Score Booster, however in this case it looks like the files aren't being compressed.

Any suggestions?

Also i've added the GZip compression code to .HTACCESS file and its not showing any improvement.

Comment: Try to restart your server

Answer (score 0):

Compression for JS/CSS is best handled on the webserver (and AO tries to educate Apache using a .htaccess), but if can't get that working you can disable the "serve as static files" advanced option in which case your autoptimized CSS/ JS (but not SVG or non-optimized files) will be served by PHP-code which will take care of compression for your.

hope this helps,
frank (ao dev)

Comment: what do you mean "PHP-code which will take care of compression"? how? please explain in-depth

Comment: If "save as static files" is not checked, AO will save the optimized JS/ CSS as PHP-files and inject references to those in the HTML. When those files are requested, The php-code will check the accept encoding HTTP request header and based on that decide how to compress the result (gzip or deflate) and send it to the browser.